# Spectral decomposition and equivalance

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory

I want to prove bu using spectral decomposition that $${\left\| {{\partial _x}{{(1 - \partial _x^2)}^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}h} \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}} \le C{\left\| h \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}}$$
it is well known that the operator $${T:=(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}:{L^2}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L) \subset {L^2}(0,L)$$ is linear continuous, self-adjoint and compact and positive definite, so there exists a Hilbertian basis of eigenvectors of $T$. So for all function belonging to ${L^2}(0,L)$ we can write $$f = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} {{a_n}\sin ({{n\pi x} \over L})} $$ 
and define the operator $$A: = {\partial _x}{(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}$$
so $$Af = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} {{{\lambda _n^2} \over {\lambda _n^2 + 1}}{a_n}\sin ({{n\pi x} \over L})} $$
where ${({\lambda _n})_{n \ge 0}}$ is a sequence of eigenvalues of $T$.

My question is: how can I prove the inequality above by using this decomposition? and is this decomposition is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use Parseval's identity an the fact that
$$
\Bigl|\frac{\lambda_n^2}{\lambda_n^2+1}\,a_n\Bigr|\le|a_n|.
$$

Comment: Thank you sir, is there any conditions on $f$ so satisfy this decomposition or it is true for all function in $L^2$ ?

Comment: $\{\sin(\pi nx/L)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a complete orthogonal system on $L^2(0,L)$, so the expansion is valid for all $f\in L^2(0,L)$.

Comment: So sir, the function $f$ is not have to be in $H_0^1(0,L)$ or in some space? Thanks.

Comment: You define first $A$ on $H^1$, but then, because of the inequality, you can extend it to all of $L^2$.

Comment: Ok...so I will write the proof rigorously..: we have  $${(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}:{L^2}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L)$$ and  $${\partial _x}:{H^1}(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$ so $${\partial _x}{(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}:{H^1}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \subset {L^2}(0,L)$$  . Now  we know that ${\{ \sin ({{n\pi x} \over L})\} _{n \ge 1}}$ is a basis of ${L^2}(0,L)$ and it denses in $H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L)$ ( Is ${\{ \sin ({{n\pi x} \over L})\} _{n \ge 1}}$ is a basis of ${H^1}(0,L)$ ?

Comment: Can I say : ${\{ \sin ({{n\pi x} \over L})\} _{n \ge 1}}$ is dense in $H_0^1(0,L)$ and $H_0^1(0,L) \subset  {H^1}(0,L)$ so it denses too in ${H^1}(0,L)$... and one makes the known steps?